# How to change wordpress registration form submit button value?

Tags: css, buttons

I am trying to create a website with wordpress and I want to change the text value of the submit button (included in the pictures). When I change its' text value while inspecting the element, it changes successfully, but when I do it with custom CSS, it fails. What code should I write to the custom CSS file to successfully change the buttons' text value?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you would have many options to change button text like jquery and if you know about that registration form from where it is coming from.

By using jquery you would have to add below code at the end of the footer.php file like as below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Change text of input button
    $(".ur-submit-button").prop("value", "Input New Text");
   // Change text of button element
   $(".ur-submit-button").html("Button New Text");
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ur-submit-button").text('your button text');
});
```